# Can I repair a HFS+ volume if the files were unreadable after "Easus Recovery Wizard" recovery? Testdisk & Diskutil info below

Tags: osx, data-recovery, uefi, hfs+, testdisk

I have someone else's 1.5TB hard drive (WD Elements) that I would like to repair or recover files from. It has possibly been dropped and was constantly around a lot of loud Techno music. It is the standard format from OSX; EFI table, with a HFS+ file system taking up the entire disk.

On owner's request we used *Easus Recovery Wizard,* which found all the files, but then after, the files recovered were all unreadable; I don't have those files anymore, but the user reported OSX could not recognize any of the files as the types reported, or open the files at all.  I don't have *Spinrite* or any other commercial recovery software around.

On OSX the disk doesn't mount.

**Disk Utility** GUI in OSX says that the partition table is in-tact and recreates a windows boot.ini file, but it will not mount the HFS+ file-system and says something like [I am paraphrasing this from another language]:

```
"Incorrect node size of B-Tree-Headers, Exit code 8, do "Repair Volume"
```

...after clicking repair it gives the same message, and additionally...

```
"It is recommended to repair the Boot-Support-Partition"
"Failure of the Disk Utility, save your data somewhere else."
```

**Testdisk** reports on the quick scan:

```
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 16 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 32 (FAT) != 63 (HD)

EFI System 46 409645 409600 [EFI]
Mac HFS 409640 2929948631 2929538992
```

but then shows the table and partition as in-tact (green colored on the terminal screen), and like the other recovery software, it also will allow me to make a disk image.

I did the entire "Deep Scan" of Testdisk, which just came up with no additional partitions found.

Any **tips on whether to proceed, and how to possibly recover the files,** or what further, exact data would be truly of use to help repair the disk would be really appreciated.

Comment: This tutorial was written in 2013 but try this. He is using TestDisk to find the partition info and using pdisk utility to repair it [Repair a Mac OS X HFS+ Partition table](https://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/)